# Android OpenGLES - Cube not showing on some devices

Tags: android, opengl-es

I recently used moho example to create a cube in android with OpenGLES 1.1 and I don't know why it works on some devices and not work on others with same Android version.

If someone can help me...

This is MyGLRenderer:

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    Context context;   // Application's context
    private Cube cube;
    private Triangle triangle;

    private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

    // Constructor with global application context
    public MyGLRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cube = new Cube();
        this.triangle = new Triangle();
        initRotationMatrix();
    }

    private void initRotationMatrix() {
        mRotationMatrix[0] = 1;
        mRotationMatrix[4] = 1;
        mRotationMatrix[8] = 1;
        mRotationMatrix[12] = 1;
    }

    // Call back when the surface is first created or re-created
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Set color's clear-value to black
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);            // Set depth's clear-value to farthest
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enables depth-buffer for hidden surface removal
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);    // The type of depth testing to do
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);  // nice perspective view
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading of color
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);      // Disable dithering for better performance

        // You OpenGL|ES initialization code here
        // ......
    }

    // Call back after onSurfaceCreated() or whenever the window's size changes
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (height == 0) height = 1;   // To prevent divide by zero
        float aspect = (float)width / height;

        // Set the viewport (display area) to cover the entire window
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        // Setup perspective projection, with aspect ratio matches viewport
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select projection matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset projection matrix
        // Use perspective projection
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);  // Select model-view matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset
    }

    // Call back to draw the current frame.
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Clear color and depth buffers using clear-value set earlier
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // ----- Render the Color Cube -----
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                // Reset the model-view matrix
        gl.glTranslatef(cube.getPosX(), cube.getPosY(), cube.getPosZ()); // Translate
        gl.glScalef(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);      // Scale down (NEW)
        gl.glRotatef(cube.getAngleX(), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // rotate about the axis (1, 1, 1) (NEW)
        gl.glRotatef(cube.getAngleY(), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // rotate about the axis (1, 1, 1) (NEW)
        gl.glRotatef(cube.getAngleZ(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // rotate about the axis (1, 1, 1) (NEW)
        gl.glMultMatrixf(mRotationMatrix, 0);

        //cube.setAngleX(cube.getAngleX() - 1.5f);
        //cube.setAngleY(cube.getAngleY() - 1.5f);
        //cube.setAngleZ(cube.getAngleZ() - 1.5f);

        // LIGHT
//      float[] position = {0f, -5f, 0f, 1f};
//      float[] ambient = {1f, 1f, 1f, 1f};
//      float[] direction = {0f, 1f, 0f};

//      gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_POSITION, position, 0);
//      gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
//      gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, direction, 0);
//      gl.glLightf(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 100.0f);
//
//      gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
//      gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);

        cube.draw(gl);
//        triangle.draw(gl);
    }

    public Cube getCube() {
        return cube;
    }

    public float[] getmRotationMatrix() {
        return mRotationMatrix;
    }
}
```

This is my Cube class:

```
public class Cube {
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;  // Buffer for vertex-array
    private int numFaces = 6;

    private float posX = 0.0f, posY = 0.0f, posZ = -6.0f;
    private float angleX = 0.0f,  angleY = 0.0F, angleZ = 0.0f;

    /*
    private float[][] colors = {  // Colors of the 6 faces
            {1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // 0. orange
            {1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},  // 1. purple
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // 2. green
            {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},  // 3. blue
            {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // 4. red
            {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}   // 5. yellow
    };
    */

    private float[][] colors = {  // Colors of the 6 faces
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // green
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // green
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // green
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // green
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // green
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}   // green
    };

    private float[] vertices = {  // Vertices of the 6 faces
            // FRONT
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            // BACK
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
            1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
            // LEFT
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front 
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
            // RIGHT
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
            // TOP
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
            1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
            // BOTTOM
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f   // 1. right-bottom-front
    };

    // Constructor - Set up the buffers
    public Cube() {
        // Setup vertex-array buffer. Vertices in float. An float has 4 bytes
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Use native byte order
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); // Convert from byte to float
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);         // Copy data into buffer
        vertexBuffer.position(0);           // Rewind
    }

    // Draw the shape
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);    // Front face in counter-clockwise orientation
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);    // Cull the back face (don't display)

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

        // Render all the faces
        for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
            // Set the color for each of the faces
            gl.glColor4f(colors[face][0], colors[face][1], colors[face][2], colors[face][3]);
            // Draw the primitive from the vertex-array directly
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, face * 4, 4);
        }
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

    public float getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    public void setPosX(float posX) {
        this.posX = posX;
    }

    public float getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }

    public void setPosY(float posY) {
        this.posY = posY;
    }

    public float getPosZ() {
        return posZ;
    }

    public void setPosZ(float posZ) {
        this.posZ = posZ;
    }

    public float getAngleX() {
        return angleX;
    }

    public void setAngleX(float angleX) {
        this.angleX = angleX;
    }

    public float getAngleY() {
        return angleY;
    }

    public void setAngleY(float angleY) {
        this.angleY = angleY;
    }

    public float getAngleZ() {
        return angleZ;
    }

    public void setAngleZ(float angleZ) {
        this.angleZ = angleZ;
    }
```

Comment: i guess it would make sense to mention the android version and the devices you tested, as it might not be a code related problem.

Comment: It work on Sony D6603 Android 5.0.2 (API 21)
It doesn't work on Unknown BS1078 Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok. I think it's related to your device. Whether your device support OpenGLES1.1? Did you try to use some code like

```
mGlSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(1);
```

to define the version. Maybe the device's default OpenGLES version is 2.0(or the device do not support version 1.1). I am not sure about this, but I think it maybe an idea.